# Получить часть строки php (preg_match)

Tags: php

Есть html-разметка, которая идет в виде строки в php, в ней есть следующая строка:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="1500924179:J+qsBWRoHUzoTYrHRfO3Sj6ZS2w=" />
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="1500924179:J+qsBWRoHUzoTYrHRfO3Sj6ZS2w=" />
<input type="hidden" name="asdasd" value="asdvzx:J+asd=" />
<input type="text" name="hello" value=xczxc"z=" />
</body>
</html>
```

Необходимо получить все, что лежит в value, от " до ", опираясь именно на name="csrf", ибо input'ов в html будет много. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно через `ajax` запрос запрос брать значение и передавать в `php`.

Comment: @МаксимБуяков к сожалению, такой возможности нет

Comment: @Alexxosipov, этот инпут  используется для предотвращения несанкционированной отправки формы  ? например в Yii ? если не секрет, зачем вам данный security session key ? ))

Comment: да кстати, оптимально будет сделать парсинг HTML DOM

Comment: @Arsen мне это нужно для парсинга баланса личных кабинетов моих аккаунтов) в сервисе стоит защита, нужно перед каждым входом заходить в дерево, брать value и отправлять вместе с формой)

Comment: )) странно конечно..... если вы делаете данные действия на своём сайте , данный ключ вы можете получить и в коде  PHP (вызвав функцию) но по всей вероятности вы пробуйте несанкционированно сделать отправку форм. Если сайты,  которые вы хотите "парсить" сделаны знатоком...  вам данный ключ не поможет ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="1500924179:J+qsBWRoHUzoTYrHRfO3Sj6ZS2w=" />
</body>
</html>';
// <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="1500924179:J+qsBWRoHUzoTYrHRfO3Sj6ZS2w=" />
preg_match('~name="csrf" value="([^"]+)"~i', $str , $a);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($a[1]); echo '</pre>';
// 1500924179:J+qsBWRoHUzoTYrHRfO3Sj6ZS2w="
```

Comment: А как это вырезать из всей строки html? P.s. <input type="hidden" name="csrf" встречается там единожды

Comment: @Alexxosipov отредактируйте ваш первый пост с учётом этих предпочтений.

Comment: Отредактировал)

Comment: @Alexxosipov я свой ответ тоже подправил.

Comment: Я опять немного неправильно написал, в html может быть много инпутов. Буду внимательнее с составлением вопроса)

Comment: Почему никто не пытается парсить html?

Comment: @Alexxosipov снова ответ подправил.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko в названии же _(preg_match)_ запрошена